# JQuery Ajax running success callback if defaults to true

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created code which works, it posts, an ajax call.  It also posts a success message.  I want to add validation to the click function. So it only runs $.ajax if validation is true.  I have a form validation script for this.

It is a syntax issue I can not find what though

ajax

```
  $(document).ready ( function () {
        $('#go').click (function () {


       $.ajax ( {
                type:       'POST',
                data:       $('#newsletter').serialize (),
                url:        $('#newsletter').attr ('action'),
                success:   function(){



                                $('#thankYou').show (
                                    1000,
                                    function () {
                                        setTimeout ( function() { $('#thankYou').hide(1000); }, 3000);
                                    }
                                );


            }

            } );
            return false;
        } );
    } )
```

I want to run checkform()  inside $('#go').click and only if form passes run $.ajax as a callback of checkform.

```
function checkform() {
  for (i=0;i<fieldstocheck.length;i++) {
    if (eval("document.subscribeform.elements['"+fieldstocheck[i]+"'].type") == "checkbox") {
      if (document.subscribeform.elements[fieldstocheck[i]].checked) {
      } else {
        alert("Please enter your "+fieldnames[i]);
        eval("document.subscribeform.elements['"+fieldstocheck[i]+"'].focus()");
        return false;
      }
    }
    else {
      if (eval("document.subscribeform.elements['"+fieldstocheck[i]+"'].value") == "") {
        alert("Please enter your "+fieldnames[i]);
        eval("document.subscribeform.elements['"+fieldstocheck[i]+"'].focus()");
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  for (i=0;i<groupstocheck.length;i++) {
    if (!checkGroup(groupstocheck[i],groupnames[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  if(! compareEmail())
  {
    alert("Email Addresses you entered do not match");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var fieldstocheck = new Array();
var fieldnames = new Array();
function addFieldToCheck(value,name) {
  fieldstocheck[fieldstocheck.length] = value;
  fieldnames[fieldnames.length] = name;
}
var groupstocheck = new Array();
var groupnames = new Array();
function addGroupToCheck(value,name) {
  groupstocheck[groupstocheck.length] = value;
  groupnames[groupnames.length] = name;
}

function compareEmail()
{
  return (document.subscribeform.elements["email"].value == document.subscribeform.elements["emailconfirm"].value);
}
function checkGroup(name,value) {
  option = -1;
  for (i=0;i<document.subscribeform.elements[name].length;i++) {
    if (document.subscribeform.elements[name][i].checked) {
      option = i;
    }
  }
  if (option == -1) {
    alert ("Please enter your "+value);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

markup

```
<div id="container">
<form id="newsletter"  method="post" action="http://www.officeyoganyc.com/lists/?p=subscribe" name="subscribeform"><input type="hidden" name="formtoken" value="a7d1884b463ed70e91fb62a5121e9846" />

<div id="fieldWrapper">
<div class="fieldHolder">
  <div class="attributeinput1"><input type=text name=email value="email" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="on" size="12"/> 
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">addFieldToCheck("email","Email");</script></div> 
  </div>


  <div class="fieldHolder2">
  <div class="attributeinput2"><input type=text name=emailconfirm value="confirm email" autocomplete="off" size="12"/> 
  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">addFieldToCheck("emailconfirm","Confirm your email address");</script></div>
        </div> 
        </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="list[1]" value="signup">
  <input type="hidden" name="listname[1]" value="office yoga list"/>
  <div style="display:none"><input type="text" name="VerificationCodeX" value="" size="20"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe"/>
<div id="subscribe"><input type=image src="http://www.officeyoganyc.com/themes/zen/zen/images/yogaSubmit.png" id="go" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe onClick="return checkform();"></div>
    </form>

    </div>
  <div id="thankYou">Thank You For Signing Up</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the "syntax issue"?  What's the code that doesn't work or causes an error (and what exactly is the error)?

Comment: `eval("document.subscribeform.elements['"+fieldstocheck[i]+"'].type" === document.subscribeform.elements[fieldstocheck[i]].type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex,

The checkForm function returns a boolean indicating success or failure, then put an if statement as below just above the ajax but inside the click event so you have the ajax called only if checkform gives true, otherwise write the else portion to alert the user to fix whatever is wrong.

```
if(checkform()) {
   $.ajax(.....)
} else {
   alert("Validation Failed");
}
```

On a side note, I caution you extremely highly not to rely on the javascript (client-side) validation only - you need to make sure your server script called by the ajax also checks to make sure the form post data hasn't been doctored to hack you.  Forewarned.

R

Comment: I tried this solution but got this error from firebug SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Comment: ahh I wasn't putting it in the function, but inside the click(). thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the function `checkgroup` and a few other functions, you are asking the function to return a true, after you already had it `return false;`. When it runs into that `return false;`, the function stops there. So what you need to do is decide whether you want a `return false` or a return true. Do not put the `return true;` without the else

Comment: I want click to return false i just want the jquery .show function inside the function to run revealing the div. thanks Ross for helping me solve this.